# Select query from db using linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a entity class called

```
[Serializable]
Public sealed class LayEntity : EntityBase
{
    Public string Name {get;set;}  // Getting mapped to the same column name in db table
}
```

In my .cs file I have a query as :

```
LayEntity lay = null;
Using(var context = new DBContext())
{
   lay = context.LayTable.where(x=>x.id >1).Select (y=>y.Name).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My intention is to store retrieve the name filed on to the entityclass.
But I am getting a compile time error as **‘Cannot implicitly convert string to Entity’**.What is that I need to do?

Comment: Why don't post code, that at least compiles?

Comment: You select `y => y.Name` which is a `string` and try to assign it to `lay` which is a `LayEntity`. Remove `.Select(y=>y.Name)` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most probably do this:

```
lay = context.LayTable
            .Where(x=>x.id >1)
            .Select (y=>new LayEntity (){Name=y.Name})
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or this:

```
lay = context.LayTable.where(x=>x.id >1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or even this:

```
lay = context.LayTable.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id >1);
```

If you expect a single value I would do this:

```
lay = context.LayTable.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id >1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Error message is clear, you cannot assign `string` value to object of type `LayEntity`

Probably, what you need is

```
LayEntity lay = null;
Using(var context = new DBContext())
{
   lay = context.LayTable.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id >1);

   if(lay != null)
   {
       lay.Name; // use name here.
   }
}
```

Note, I've removed `Where` method as it is redundant in this case.